# Mapping a "Has-A" relationship in Hibernate JPA with different Parent Classes

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "OptionalCommonData")
public class OptionalCommonData {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)        
    private Long id;

    private String commonPropertyA;
    private String commonPropertyB;
    private String commonPropertyC;
    private String commonPropertyD;

}
```

I have an entity like the above.  Many other entity classes will  have this optional common data available to it as a `has-a` relationship.  How should I go about implementing this so that the OptionalCommonData class and table can be reused?

If it wasn't being resued, I would just add this to the parent class:

```
@OneToOne(mappedBy = "parentObject", optional = true)
private OptionalCommonData optionalCommonData;
```

Then add this to the OptionalCommonData:

```
@OneToOne
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "parent_id")
ParentClass parentObject;
```

Comment: If your application is spring managed then make sure you are not using the default scope, change it to prototype.

Comment: Why not simply use a unidirectional one-to-one association? Just put `@OneToOne` without `mappedBy` on top of `optionalCommonData` and the foreign key will end up in the parent table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to implement inheritance in hibernate, it provides four main solutions:

- Using `@MappedSuperclass` annotation.
- Using `@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)`
- Using `@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)`
- Using `@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)`

You can read about all this options, advantages and disadvantages with examples in the JPA and hibernate in action book: https://livebook.manning.com/book/java-persistence-with-hibernate-second-edition/chapter-6/1.

Briefly:

- @MappedSuperclass annotation can be used when your parent class is not an entity (thus it won't map in the database table) and you don't need polymorphic queries (such as SELECT ocd FROM OptionalCommonData ocd).
- Strategy SINGLE_TABLE is using when you want to achieve high performance through denormalization.
- Strategy TABLE_PER_CLASS is similar with @MappedSuperclass, but polymorphic queries are performed with UNION commands.
- And in JOINED strategy child tables are not inherits data from the parent class because they use foreign keys, you can use this strategy when you need polymorphic queries.

In your situation, it is better to use the @Inheritance annotation.